# GoogleMaps Android studio change language refresh

Tags: android, google-maps, reload

I am using a google map in an activity with multiple fragments, when changing the language from English to Arabic and vice versa from the settings page, i reload the whole activity to apply changes, every thing displays normally ei all text changes to the new language except the titles inside the map (country names, city, streets...)

this is the code i use to change the laguage:

```
 public static void setLanguage(Activity activity){
        String languageToLoad = "en";
        boolean isEnglish=Preference.getBooleanPrefs(Preference.LANGUAGE, activity, true);
        if(isEnglish)
            languageToLoad = "en";
        else
            languageToLoad = "ar";

        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        activity.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    }
```

this is the code i use to reload the activity:

```
public void refreshChangelanguage() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        loadFragment(FRAGMENT_SETTING, null);

    }
```

the map keeps displaying in the old language until i kill the whole app from the stack list manually then reopen it, how can i force the map to reload the labels in the new language?

thank you in advance

Comment: hey did you got the answer ? I tried the below one and its not working for me. Also when i came back from map the language was changing automatically to default one.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say you have to do the `setLanguage(Activity activity)` after the `super.onCreate` and before the `setContentView` on the Activity.

Comment: thank you for replying, i did that but it is not working